# Reverse Geocoding: Address not showing for India

Tags: android, gps, reverse-geocoding

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 100);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                                     if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                              Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    result.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getCountryName()); }
```

I'm trying to reverse geocode and fetch adresses, I'm able to get addresses for US but not for India. Any idea how to crack this ?

Comment: can you post your code.. we can look into it

Comment: Reverse geocoding relies on an address database, which in case it has no addresses in some regions can't give you a result. That could be a reason but it could very well be your code that has issues. Try google maps in the same place. If they have no address, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: how do you reverse geocode? how does it fail?

Comment: agree with @Tech.Rahul place code when ask question...

Comment: try yahoo api for reverse coding.. here is the link ... http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-reverse-geocoding-yahoo-api.html

Comment: Rahul- I tried this one. He is using HTTPClient and connecting to Yahoo. I don't want to do that. It's gonna make the app slow.

Comment: Jigar- I have tried all eveything that was avaailable Online and on Stack Overflow and finally asked this question hoping if anyone had faced a similar issue with the Indian addresses.